# How to get UIs elments' position (or space) in Godot 4.0

Tags: user-interface, onclick, 2d, game-development, godot

I am making a game with Godot 4.0.stable where you can move characters around a 2D Top Down planet by clicking on the position you wish the character to move to, just like in Rimworld.

I would like to implement UI elements such as a button to switch scene, a fast foward, a pause etc...

**However my issue is that when I click on UI elements it moves the player to the coordinate under the UI element.**

For example here : https://prnt.sc/0VtHloCDBNiO
The red character is chosen, when I click on the top left button the function associate to the button is used but the player will still moves under the button.
I would like to know if there is a way to do somehting like :

```
If Input.is_action_just_pressed("left_click") and click_position != UI_elements_space:
    #move the character
else:
    #dont move the character
```

I tried to get every UI elements position and multiply by them by their size so I can add it so the condition. But I have to implement every new element of the UI this condition, which is pretty tedious and not clean.

I know there is a better and much easier way to do it. I just don't know how...

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor your project so you:

- Use [`Control`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_control.html) and derived types for your UI.
- Don't use [`Input`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_input.html) for pointing input. Either use [`_input`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-input) or [`_input_event`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_collisionobject2d.html#class-collisionobject2d-method-input-event).

And then the `Control`s will consume the input before it gets to the game world.

*In fact, the issue most people have with pointing input is the opposite as yours: that the `Control` is preventing their game world from getting it. Which you can handle with [`mouse_filter`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_control.html#class-control-property-mouse-filter).*

See also: [Using InputEvent](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/inputs/inputevent.html).

Comment: Hello, I am already using Control and derived types for my UI.
When I try using Either use _input or _input_event it seems like it is glitched. It works sometimes and sometimes not... You can see my code below


`func _unhandled_input(event: InputEvent) -> void:
 if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
  if event.button_mask == MOUSE_BUTTON_MASK_LEFT:
   print("Left click")`

Comment: @Nicolas01 Notice that there is `InputEventMouseMotion` for motion, and `InputEventMouseButton` for press and release. So your code would be detecting a drag, not a click.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. English is not my native language so I didn't notice they were a difference between `InputEventMouseMotion` and `InputEventMouseButton`. I marked you as best answer